# Is Wolfram Alpha linear independence wrong or am I missing something?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, wolfram-alpha

Maybe it's because you can't ask those questions to wolfram & I should use a matrix instead but when imputting

> linear independence {$t$, $t^2+1$, $t^2+1-t$}

It says the three functions are linearly independent when the third one is clearly a linear combination of the other two. How should I input this to get a valid answer? I wanna check whether or not my results are correct.

Comment: Entering `linear independence {t, t, t}` also gives `(t,t,t) is linearly independent`.

Comment: linear independence {(0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, -1, 1)}

Comment: This kind of problem is the price to pay if you use some more or less _guessed_ pseudo-syntax, in which brackets have no proper fixed meaning. Wolfram|Alpha is a very useful tool, but don't forget it's more a google than a CAS.

Comment: @leftaroundabout  what a nice, polite way of saying "rtfm"  :-)

Comment: Wolfram Alpha? Wrong? :o

Comment: @Carl: There's an m?

Comment: @Hurkyl online, anyway.  The last time I read a Mathematica manual was a number of yrs ago; dunno if you still get one w/ purchase.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's because WolframAlpha interprets your input as *one* vector, i.e. the space of the single vector $(t, t^2+1, t^2+1-t)$.

An appropriate input would be (treating $1$, $t$ and $t^2$ as basis vectors):

> linear independence (0,1,0), (1,0,1), (1,-1,1)

which outputs `linearly dependent`.

You can find other input examples for linear algebra [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Matrices.html).

Comment: Ah, I see now thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can wolfram only do polynimials? What if I want to check the linear dependence of $\{ \sin x, x \}$ for example?

Answer (score 9):

Another way to check for linear independence in W|A is to compute the Wronskian, say with the input ["wronskian(($t$, $t^2+1$, $t^2+1-t$), $t$)"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=wronskian((t,+t%5E2%2B1,t%5E2%2B1-t),t)), which results in $0$ so the set of functions is indeed linearly dependent.